# cannot GET error

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando de hacer una base de datos con MySql con un archivo php.
Al correr mi archivo html en el buscador, me aparece un error de cannot GET/connect.php

Este es mi archivo form.html

```html
<div class="form-box">
        <div class="button-box">
            <div id="btn"></div>
            <button type="button" class="toggle-btn" onclick="login()">LogIn</button>
            <button type="button" class="toggle-btn" onclick="register()">Register</button>
        </div>
        <form id="login" action="/connect.php" class="input-group" method="POST">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Email" required>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check-box"><span>Remember password?</span>
            <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Log In</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Y este es mi archivo connect.php

```js
<?php

$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
if (!empty($email)) {
    if (!empty($password)) {
        $host = "localhost";
        $dbusername = "root";
        $dbpassword = "";
        $dbname = "mydb";


        $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ')' . mysqli_connect_error());
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO loginform (email, password) values('$email', '$password')";
            if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                echo "new record is insterted succesfully";
            } else {
                echo "error: " . $sql . "br" . $conn->error;
            }
            $conn->close();
        }
    } else {
        echo "password should not be empty";
        die();
    }
} else {
    echo "email should not be empty";
    die();
}

?>
```

Los 2 archivos estan en la misma carpeta, y he intentado poniendolos en diferentes carpetas y sigue sin funcionar.
Alguien me podria ayudar con esta?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Este es el sitio en castellano, por favor, traduce tu pregunta o plantéala en el sitio en inglés.

Comment: ahi está! pensé que estaba en ingles